# Why can't I center these two images in a div holder?

Tags: html, css

My code below, I just want to center align everything, but I can't figure out it wouldn't work in the same way as all other divs.

EDIT; Added the HTML from above. This is probably the reason, something affecting the model, but I can't figure out why....grrrr

And also, I have no CSS, the only CSS file is for the form in a different div. Everything else is in line ftw.

```
--------------
<div id="softphone-enable" style="float: right; position: relative; top: -15px">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <label>Enable: </label>
        <input name="sft-enable" id="sft-enable" type="checkbox" value="0">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
 </div>
--------------
 <div class="section">Provisioning</div>

    <div id="softphone-main">

      <div id="softphone-links" style="text-align: center;>

        <a href="https://play.google.com" target="_blank">

          <img id="android-img" style="height: 60px; width: 200px;"  border="0" src="/Images/google-play-badge.png" alt="android" /></a>

        <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/" target="_blank">

          <img id="osx-img" style="height: 60px; width: 200px;"  border="0" src="/Images/app-store-badge.png" alt="osx" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please include the css you're using. Ideally create a code snippet so that we can run it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It looks center aligned to me...

Comment: any code snippet would be just copying the above code, not worth it I think.

Comment: Are the images block level?  If not that may be your problem.  Also text-align: center, (not 100% recommended) also works on images.

Comment: If you've figured out the solution to your problem, please post an answer, rather than editing your question to contain the answer. Also, please [edit] your question so that it's got a [mcve], ideally in a code snippet, so we can easily edit and test when trying to answer (there's a button under code snippets that lets you render the result, and another that lets you copy the snippet to your answer)

Comment: it's still an issue, though, will not center

Comment: @juju Please post the css that goes along with your code for help.

Comment: @juju Did you find the solution that you needed?

Comment: @Andrew Ice - yeah I'm fairly sure that the <p> tags were screwing the layout but I didn't find out why.

Comment: @juju you should post it out and close this question with your answer.  In case anyone else ever may run into the same problem.  They can come here and realize their mistake too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your helpful posts, I've just removed some silly legacy code, and now I've made it work with;

```
<div id="softphone-enable" style="float: right; position: relative; top: -5px">
    <label>Enable: </label>
    <input name="sft-enable" id="sft-enable" type="checkbox" value="0">
</div>

<div class="section">Provisioning</div>

<div id="softphone-main">
<div id="sft-links" style="text-align: center;">
//etc...
```

As to why the top section was affecting the below div placement, I'm going to blame

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<div id="softphone-enable" style="text-align: center">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <label>Enable: </label>
    <input name="sft-enable" id="sft-enable" type="checkbox" value="0">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div class="section">
    <div style="text-align: center">Provisioning</div>
</div>
<div id="softphone-main">

    <div id="softphone-links" style="text-align: center;">

        <a href="https://play.google.com" target="_blank">

            <img id="android-img" style="height: 60px; width: 200px;" border="0" src="/Images/google-play-badge.png" alt="android" /></a>

        <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/" target="_blank">

            <img id="osx-img" style="height: 60px; width: 200px;" border="0" src="/Images/app-store-badge.png" alt="osx" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately can't do this as I have more stuff underneath these which would be affected by the catch all text-align

Comment: there are 3 element in your code. one text "Provisioning" and two images. I saw that two images are already in center but text are not. If images are in the div "section" then add the text into another div and make that align center.

Comment: ah yeah ok, so you just want to align the text?

Comment: yap. actually what do you want ? am i missing anything ?

Answer (score 1):

Without your CSS we cannot properly answer the problem directly.
Most likely if trying to center, your anchor tags are set to block level elements.

If your images are not centering with margin: 0 auto, it's probably due to them being inline elements.  Set them to block, and this should help the issue.  Also, text-align: center; on the anchor tags would be a good fallback.

```
<a href="#" class="block">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</a>
<a href="#" class="block">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</a>

a.block {
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  /* text-align: center; */
}
a.block img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/keq85yao/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  #softphone-links a{
    display:block;
  }

  #softphone-links img{
     margin: auto;
  }
```

Comment: no  luck, this bunched them on top of each other, I'm looking to center align both on the same line, I've done it before with images but just can't figure out how...Also, edited my question a litlle

Answer (score 0):

The links with the images seems to be aligned in the center.
There might be something in your CSS that overrides the code you provided.